# Assigning IAM Roles to Users via API

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I saw that there is a Beta available that allows you to add and remove members from a project inside GCP (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/user-accounts/api/latest/users/insert). I could not however find a sister API that would allow the permission level of that user in relation to the project to be manipulated.

Is this feature in a different section of the API documentation or is it not yet available?

Answer (score 1):

The API you link to is for adding users to a GCE instance. See this instead: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users

For IAM, see https://cloud.google.com/iam/reference/rest/

Comment: Thank you for the links - The link I provided is for adding links to Google Cloud Platform - not Google Apps for Work.

I am particularly looking for a solution to manipulate permissions inside the cloud platform for normal users. The second link you provided currently only exposes ServiceAccounts and does not appear to allow management of routine accounts. Do you know if that is the case?

Comment: You set the IAM policy on the particular resource. For example, see this page for setting the policy on projects: https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/setIamPolicy.